# Google Script: GmailApp.sendEmail with name option in Cyrillic

Tags: gmail

I'm trying to send an email [using GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) as follows:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("myemail@gmail.com", 
    "EmailTopic + Русский язык", "EmailBody + Русский язык", 
    {name: "Sent From"}
);
```

and it works with Russian language in topic and email body.

But when I add Cyrillic symbols to "name" option, it won't send an email at all:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("myemail@gmail.com",
     "EmailTopic + Русский язык", "EmailBody + Русский язык", 
     {name: "Sent From + Русский язык"}
);
```

So Cyrillic symbols are effectively supported everywhere but the sender name. Is there a workaround, or any fix for that?